# Using date command to print the current date

Tags: linux, fedora, date

I am trying to find a way to use the `date` linux command to print `Today is June 8, 2021`
A search in man pages didn't reveal anything containing `Today is` in output 
Is it possible to use just `date` command to print the current date in the above format

Answer (score 1):

Use `Today is` in the format verbatim:

```
date '+Today is %B %-d, %Y'
```

See `man 1 date` to learn about tokens like `%B`. Note `%-d` prints `8` where `%d` would print `08`.

`%B` prints locale's full month name. In any English locale the above command should just work. If your locale is non-English then you need to set `LC_TIME` to some English locale to get `June`. `C` locale should be available in any system and it will give you English month names:

```
LC_TIME=C date '+Today is %B %-d, %Y'
```